# how to trim a string into two Integers and one string (php)?

Tags: php, string, int, str-replace, explode

I have a question variable e.g. "4X9"

how can i split this into 3 different variables, to have an integer 4, integer 9 and string X ?

I tried using

```
$arr = explode('X', $question);
    $before = $arr[0];

    $bbefore = str_replace('"', "", $before);
  $newBefore =(int)$before;`
```

and the same for after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list($before, $x, $after) = str_split(str_replace('"', '', $question));
```

1. Explode string by character using [`str_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)
2. Use [`list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to make assigning them variables clearer
3. If `$before` and/or `$after` are integers you can cast them after this line of code

   list($before, $x, $after) = str_split(str_replace('"', '', $question));
   $before = (int) $before;
   $after  = (int) $after;

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jnPSUK)

Comment: the value of both $before and $after = 0 for some reason :/ Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: the question is "5 X 7" 

maybe i need to strip the "" ?

Comment: I used the wrong function to split the string. See my updated answer. Here's a working demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/tSO2n9

Comment: If the question marks are part of the value we should strip them out. Let me add that to my code.

Comment: yes when I echo the question it shows the question marks, so they should be stripped

Comment: Thank you, its better, but now $before works but $after is still 0 :S

Comment: Can you edit [this code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tSO2n9) with yours to show it not working? That would make it easier for me to debug since the code sample I created does work. Obviously there is a disconnect somewhere.

Comment: no idea why it's not working for me, I've edited the code but it seems to be working on your site, but for me it still shows 0, strange.

the question is imported from a database, don't know if that matters.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Echo out the value and make sure it is what you are expecting.

Comment: Looks like there are extra spaces, check your link you sent me.

Comment: You need to run it and send me the new link (from the address bar)